# Python Filter/ compare every second value in a sequence

Tags: python, filter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a function that counts how many times each element is equal to 2 elements to its right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748587/how-to-make-a-function-that-counts-how-many-times-each-element-is-equal-to-2-elem)

I need help with the prompt below.  For some reason I keep on getting a "'int' object is not subscriptable" errpr and don't really know how to fix it.  I have a feeling that it has something to do with my helper function.

Here are the Tests:

```
         '''
             skip(X) counts how many times an item in 
             sequence X is equal to the item 
             "two places to the right" in X.

         Examples:

             skip("evening") is 2, once
                         for 'e' and once for 'n'   
             skipt([1,2,3,4]) is 0 
             skipt([0,0,0,0,0]) is 3, because
                         there are five 0's, but 
                         the last two can't be 
                         compared to item two places
                         to the right. 

>>> X = "onoratitatio" 
>>> skip(X)
3
>>> Y = 2*[3,1]+4*[1,5] 
>>> skip(Y)
8
>>> skip([5])
0
'''
```

Here is what I have currently created:

```
def helper(X):
    return X[0] == X[2]

def skip(X):
    return len(filter(helper,X))
```

I don't really know, but I'm about fed up with this problem.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @Mike P:Even the example word 'evening' is the same... :-)

Comment: With regard to the error you get, and if you care, try thinking about what the argument of `helper()` is given, and what you're `helper()` code actually expects. Get some clues here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#functional-programming-tools. Then again, you could just copy-paste the answer from your fellow student.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [4]: word = "mississippi"    
In [5]: word_list = [w for w in xrange(len(word) - 2) if word[w] == word[w + 2]]
In [6]: print len(word_list)
1

In [7]: word = "evening"
In [8]: word_list = [w for w in xrange(len(word) - 2) if word[w] == word[w + 2]]
In [9]: print len(word_list)
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with `filter()`, because `filter` takes a single value from an iterable and has no way to know the whole iterable you are trying to test.

What @chown is trying to tell you is that you can fix `skip()` by using the same answer your classmate got...

```
def skip(X):
    return len([w for w in xrange(len(X) - 2) if X[w] == X[w + 2]])
```

Explicitly...

```
>>> def skip(X):
...     return len([w for w in xrange(len(X) - 2) if X[w] == X[w + 2]])
... 
>>> skip('evening')
2
>>> skip([1,2,3,4])
0
>>> skip([0,0,0,0,0])
3
>>> skip("onoratitatio")
3
>>>
```